# How to set a GameObject active on one scene form a button click function on second scene that is loaded additive C#, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to coding and Unity, I'm working on a simple click style game to learn the basics of both. I've created several scenes: MainMenu, UI, 1st level and 2nd level. After pressing 'Start' in main menu i'm loading UI and 1st level additively.

In UI layer I have a shop UI and other bits that I never want to unload. On the 1st and 2nd level i have the bits that i want to have only on those scenes.

So, what I'm trying to do is when i purchase an item or upgrade for the 1st level i want a GameObject (sprite) to be set as active.

What I've tried to do is to call a function in one script that is attached to GameObject in 1st level from script that is attached to a purchase button in UI scene, but from what I was able to understand from messing with it will set that game object active if it's assigned in the UI scene - so the whole thing is basicly pointless and i can do it much easier.

Code in script attached to GameObject in 1st level scene

```
public class Work_Button : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject hubert12;

    public void Huberd()
    {
        hubert12.SetActive(true);
    }

}
```

Code in script attached to GameObject in UI scene

```
public class Shop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject buyHubertOnebutton;
    public GameObject test;

    public void UnlockHubert1()
    {

        if (Global_Cash.CashCount >= 20)
        {
            Global_Cash.CashCount -= 20;
            buyHubertOnebutton.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>().interactable = false;
            Work_Button sn = test.GetComponent<Work_Button>();
            sn.Huberd();           
        }

    }

}
```

If you have any remarks anout how i've spit scenes or anything else they will be more than welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something you need to be aware of, and that is that you can't reference an object from one scene, in another. You CAN reference the same Prefab though, but that's a slightly different issue.

One way I find effective is to do something like this:

```
public class Work_Button : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject hubert12;

    public void Awake ( )
    {
        Shop.Register ( this );
    }

    public void Huberd ( )
    {
        hubert12.SetActive ( true );
    }
}
```

Then you can have a Shop manager that has instance and static components.

```
public class Shop : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Static variables
    private static Work_Button _workButton;

    // Instance variables
    public GameObject buyHubertOnebutton;

    public static void Register ( Work_Button workButton )
    {
        _workButton = workButton;
    }

    public void UnlockHubert1 ( )
    {

        if ( Global_Cash.CashCount >= 20 )
        {
            Global_Cash.CashCount -= 20;
            buyHubertOnebutton.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button> ( ).interactable = false;
            if ( _workButton != null )
                _workButton.Huberd ( );
        }

    }
}
```

This works by having your button register with the shop. And because we're using the static variable here, we don't need to "find" the Shop object. The instance method UnlockHubert1 will check to make sure there is a button registered.

This represents just one of many ways to accomplish this. It's also the most basic of basic implementations. But as of right now I'm fond of this method. Extending this, you could store the registered items in a Dictionary collection, and you could do some cleanup/deregister when a button is destroyed (i.e. OnDestroy ).

The assumption here is that there is only one Work_Button in the scene, otherwise you'll need a way to differentiate them (i.e. a Dictionary with am identifier as the key).